# How to take a single line of input from a long running command, then kill it?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to take one line of input from a stream, pass it on as an argument and kill the stream?

In pseudo-bash code:

```sh
tail -f stream | filter | take-one-and-kill-tail | xargs use-value
```

Edit: actual script so far is:

```sh
i3-msg -t subscribe -m '["window"]'| stdbuf -o0 -e0 jq -r 'select(.change == "new") | "\(.container.window)\n"' | head -0
```

and it has following (undesirable) behaviour:

```sh
$ i3-msg -t subscribe -m '["window"]'| stdbuf -oL -eL jq -r 'select(.change == "new") | "\(.container.window)\n\n"' | head -1
# first event happens, window id is printed
79691787
# second event happens, head -1 quits
$
```

Comment: `head -n 1` may be all you need.  After it gets its one line, it should exit, which will kill everything upstream in the pipeline with `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: This kinda works, with `stdbuf -oL -eL jq`, but has an issue of quitting only after a second line would be printed, although that might just be a `jq` quirk.

Comment: Which version of bash? If you only need to support 4.3 or newer, you can get the PID of a process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the command in subshell and kill that shell.

In this example I'm killing the stream after the first info message:

```
#!/bin/bash

( sudo stdbuf -oL tail -f /var/log/syslog | stdbuf -oL grep -m1 info  ; kill $$ )
```

Note: `( pipeline )` will run the pipeline in a subshell. `$$` contains the pid of the current shell. (Which is the subshell in the above example)

---

In the above example `grep -m1` is ensuring that only one line of ouput is read/written before killing the pipe.

If your filter program does not support such an option like `-m1`, you could pipe to awk and exit awk after the first line of input. The remaining concept stays the same:

```
( sudo stdbuf -oL tail -f /var/log/syslog \
  | stdbuf -oL grep info \
  | awk '{print;exit}' ; kill $$)
```